# Extract text between two special characters

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Trying to extract the text between the special characters `"\` and `\"` through `sed`

```
Ex: "\hell@#$\"},
```

expected output : `hell@#$`

Comment: Any sample input and expected output?

Comment: "\hell@#$\"}, is the sample and the expected output would be hell@#$

Comment: Where is the text stored? Is it a file or a string in a bash-variable?

Comment: ``"\`` and ``\"`` aren't characters, they're strings. Can the text between ``"\`` and `\"` contain either ``\`` or `"`, e.g. ``abc"\foo\bar"foo\"def`` -> ``foo\bar"foo``?

Comment: What is the source of `"\hell@#$\"},` and is the only one occurrence of the pattern `...\...\...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it quite easily with using a capture-group and backreference with basic regular-expressions:

```
sed 's/^["][\]\([^\]*\).*$/\1/'
```

**Explanation**

- Normal substitution `sed 's/find/replace/`, where
- find is `^["][\]` a double-quote and `\` before beginning the capture `\(...\)` which contains `[^\]*` (zero or more characters not a `\`), the closing of the capture `\)` and then `.*$` the remainder of the string;
- replace is `\1` (the first backreference) containing the text captured between `\(...\)`.

(**note:** if your `"\` doesn't begin the string, remove the first `'^'` anchor)

**Example**

```
$ echo '"\hell@#$\"},' | sed 's/^["][\]\([^\]*\).*$/\1/'
hell@#$
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nE '/"\\[^\\]*\\+([^\\"][^\\]*\\+)*"/{s/"\\/\n/;s/.*\n//;s/\\"/\n/;P;D}' file
```

The solution comes in two parts:

Firstly, a regexp to determine whether a pair of two characters exists. This can be tricky as a negated class is insufficient because edge cases can easily defeat a simplistic approach.

Secondly, once a pair of characters does exist the text between them must be extracted piece meal.